# How to disable undesired HTML code completion for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

It's a .cshtml file, this is my code:

```
<table>
    <thread>
        <tr></tr>
    </thread>
</table>
```

When I type the `<tr` and enter `>`, the intellisense tooltip doesn't show an option for the `<tr>` tag as shown below:

[image: Screenshot of the code and tooltip I described above]

No big deal. But when I do type `>`, it automatically "corrects" my code, turning it into:

[image]

Same thing happens if I type `<tr` and hit enter. The only way I can see now to type tags like this is to go back and change what I typed.

I have failed to find any relevant option in Visual Studio>Tools>Options. What can I do?

Comment: It happens because you have `<thread>` instead of `<thead>` - that confuses intellisense. But I agree that intellisense in `Razor` pages is buggy.

Comment: Ah that's a typo on my part. But this is still a problem because there are still other times when intellisense doesn't have the tag I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to uncheck `Auto list members` in `Tools>Options>HTML>General`.
[image]

Comment: sucks that I have to do this. I don't actually mind the auto list members thing, the problem is when they get typed without me wanting it. But oh well. I also realized this isn't much of a problem unless I mistype the parent element like I have here. I'll accept your answer since I can't really find anything else on this.